# snap to closest hexagon centre in hex based grid

Tags: .net, algorithm, c++-cli, rounding, hexagonal-tiles

I am attempting to create a grid based game. so far i have a hexagonal tile based grid, with a coordinate scheme as shown below:

```
col 0
 | col 1
 |   | col 2
 |   |  |
 __  | __    __    __    __   
/00\__/02\__/04\__/06\__/08\__
\__/01\__/03\__/05\__/07\__/09\--- row 0
/10\__/12\__/14\__/16\__/18\__/
\__/11\__/13\__/15\__/17\__/19\--- row 1
/20\__/22\__/24\__/26\__/28\__/
\__/21\__/23\__/25\__/27\__/29\--- row 2
/30\__/32\__/34\__/36\__/38\__/
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__/  \__/   --- row 3
```

And looks like this in real life just with random colours for each hexagon:

[image]

What i am struggling to figure out is, when the user clicks on a hexagon how do i determine what hexagon they have clicked on?

the code i have tried so far is as follows:

```
private: System::Void MyForm_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender,
    System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {

    int CloseI=0,CloseJ=0;
    CloseJ = FindNearesetX(e->X);
    CloseI = FindNearesetY(e->Y);
    //Grid[down(y)][along(x)]
    P1.X = Grid[CloseI][CloseJ].GetX();
    P1.Y = Grid[CloseI][CloseJ].GetY();
} // END MOUSE DOWN EVENT

int FindNearesetX(int ActualX){
    int ClosestJPos;
    ClosestJPos = ((ActualX-Grid[0][0].GetX())/(1.5*HexSideLength));
    return ClosestJPos;
}//END FIND NEAREST X

int FindNearesetY(int ActualY){
    int ClosestIPos;
    ClosestIPos = ((ActualY-Grid[0][0].getY())/(HexHeight));
    return ClosestIPos;
}//END FIND NEAREST Y

private: System::Void MyForm_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender,
    System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
    this->Invalidate();

    P2.X = e->X;
    P2.Y = e->Y; 
} // END MOUSE MOVE EVENT
```

This however did not work how i wanted, this is because when the user clicks to the left of the centre point of a hexagon it snaps to the hexagon to the left of the one they clicked, and also if they click above the centre point on all odd columns it snaps to the hexagon above the one they clicked on.

I have been stuck on this one for 2 days now and really want to get it figured out. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hexagonal Grids, how do you find which hexagon a point is in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705228/hexagonal-grids-how-do-you-find-which-hexagon-a-point-is-in)

Comment: It's been 2 years since i posted this question, but i do remember seeing that post and I believe that it did not solve my problem (although i'm sure it helped), however its been too long for me to remember the specifics about why it didn't answer my question. Strange to see activity on this post after such a long time! aha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point clicked will always be closest to the center of hexagon in which the click occurs, unless the point is exactly between two hexagons in which case it will be equidistant from the two centers. The equation for the distance between two points is the SQRT( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 ).

You do not have to test the distance to every hexagon. By creating x/y thresholds you can limit the test to just nearby hexagons. For example, if hexagons have a width of 10 and the point is at (51, 73) you do not have to test hexagons with x-coordinates of < 40 or > 70.

Comment: In addition and since you are just interested in finding the nearest hexagon, you should be able to omit the square root check since the actual length won't be used for anything.  This might save you some cycles if you are checking against a lot of polygons.  Tyler's point of culling based on width is also a very fast optimization you should consider implementing and should definitely be used as a pre-test.

Comment: Right, I included the sqrt just for completeness. In an actual implementation you do not need to do the sqrt, just the sum of the squares of the differences, which is the variance between the points.

Answer (score 5):

In fact this can be done quite easily mathematically, without resorting to the irritating, scale-limiting method of iterating through a large quantity of potential values. I came up with the following code in collusion with the excellent information at the following website. The secret is to imagine your hexagonal grid is actually a plane of three-dimensional cubes.

http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

N.B. SS2DCoordinates and SS3DCoordinates are simple structs with two or three integer variables representing coordinates on a 2D and 3D grid respectively (x/y for 2D, x/y/z for 3D) Also note that my hex grid begins at 1/1 rather than 0/0.

```
SS2DCoordinates coordinatesForHexAtPoint(float a, float b)
{
    // Get basic hex information - pseudocode
    float radius = <radius of one hexagon>

    // Estimate the most likely hex and round to nearest values
    float x = 2.0/3.0*a/radius;
    float z = (1.0/3.0*sqrt(3.0)*b-1.0/3.0*a)/radius;
    float y = -x-z;

    int ix = (int)round((floor(x-y)-floor(z-x))/3.0);
    int iy = (int)round((floor(y-z)-floor(x-y))/3.0);
    int iz = (int)round((floor(z-x)-floor(y-z))/3.0);

    // Adjust to flat coordinates on the offset numbering system
    SS2DCoordinates corrected = hexToFlatCoordinates(SS3DCoordinatesMake(ix, iy, iz));
    corrected.x --;
    return axialToOffsetCoordinates(corrected);
}


SS2DCoordinates hexToFlatCoordinates(SS3DCoordinates hex)
{
    SS2DCoordinates coordinates;
    coordinates.x = hex.x;
    coordinates.y = hex.z;
    return coordinates;
}


SS2DCoordinates axialToOffsetCoordinates(SS2DCoordinates axial)
{
    SS2DCoordinates offset;
    offset.x = axial.x;
    offset.y = axial.y + (NSInteger)ceilf((float)axial.x/2.0);
    return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One should be able to find the closest hexagon with O(1) complexity:

```
    odd     even    odd    even
 0 +----+  |    |  +----+  |
   | 00 |\ |    |  | 02 |  |
   |    | \+----+  |    |  +
   |    | /| 01 |  |    |  |
 H +----+/ |    |  +----+  |
   | 10 |\ |    |  | 12 |  |
   |    | \+----+  |    |  +
   |    | /| 11 |  |    |  |
2H +----+/ |    |  +----+  |
   0....X..W.......2W......3W
```

The corners '+' are also the corners of the hexagons. 'x' DIV 2*W and y DIV H determine the correct square when 'x' mod W < X. When W <= x mod 2W <= W+X, the point is located on even columns. On odd columns, the row number is *y* DIV *H*, on even columns, it's (*y* + *H* / 2) DIV *H*.

The gray area poorly illustrated with the zig-zag pattern requires solving two linear equations (or a dot product) to determine on which side of the diagonal the point falls to. In any case there are a maximum of two candidates to select from.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, due to the regular shape of hexagons (all sides are the same length), this is as easy as cycling through your list of hexagonal tiles and figuring out which tile's center is closest to the mouse click.

C++ pseudocode:

```
//assuming "map" is an array of "Tile" pointers

Tile *closest = nullptr;
int fromClosestCenterToClick = INT_MAX;

for (int row = 0; row < map.numRows(); row++)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < map.numCols(); col++)
   {
      int distance = std::sqrt(std::pow(map[row][column]->center.x - mouseClickX, 2) + std::pow(map[row][column]->center.y - mouseClickY, 2) < fromClosestCenterToClick);
      if (distance < fromClosestCenterToClick)
      {
         closest = map[row][column];
         fromClosestCenterToClick = distance;
      }
   }
}
//closest now holds the correct tile
```

Comment: gah, you copied my answer

Comment: @TylerDurden xD I probably started typing first, but yeah.  Ironically, yours is more complete.  The thresholds are a good idea.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this answer is correct, except for me, I didn't need the `corrected.x --;` But I needed JavaScript for AfterEffects, so here, let me provide the JavaScript version.

```
function coordinatesForHexAtPoint(r, a, b)
{
    // Get basic hex information - pseudocode
    var radius = r;

    // Estimate the most likely hex and round to nearest values
    var x = 2.0/3.0*a/radius;
    var z = (1.0/3.0*Math.sqrt(3.0)*b-1.0/3.0*a)/radius;
    var y = -x-z;

    var ix = Math.round((Math.floor(x-y)-Math.floor(z-x))/3.0);
    var iy = Math.round((Math.floor(y-z)-Math.floor(x-y))/3.0);
    var iz = Math.round((Math.floor(z-x)-Math.floor(y-z))/3.0);

    // Adjust to flat coordinates on the offset numbering system
    var corrected = hexToFlatCoordinates(ix, iy, iz);
    //corrected.x--;
    
    return axialToOffsetCoordinates(corrected);
}


function hexToFlatCoordinates(ix, iy, iz)
{
    var coordinates = [];
    coordinates.x = ix;
    coordinates.y = iz;
    
    return coordinates;
}

function axialToOffsetCoordinates(axial)
{
    var offset = [];
    offset.x = axial.x;
    offset.y = axial.y + Math.ceil(axial.x/2.0);
    
    return offset;
}

var point = coordinatesForHexAtPoint(100, 100, 100);
var x = point.x;
var y = point.y;
```

This code above gave me extremely accurate results.